# Windows batch file - calculating filename from current date

Tags: command-line, batch-file

I would like to create an environment variable to hold a filename something like:

```
PREFIX-2010-AUG-09.zip
```

I can get close if I use something like this:

```
SET filename=PREFIX-%date:~-4,4%-%date:~-7,2%-%date:~0,2%.zip
```

Result:

```
PREFIX-2010-08-09.zip
```

but in this case, I get the month as two digits (08).

Is there any easy trick in Windows batch files to get the three-letter month abbreviation from the numeric month (e.g. 08 for "AUG" = August) ??

**Update:** this needs to be run on a Windows 2008 R2 Server, and yes, if someone can show me a PowerShell solution, that would work, too :-) Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Windows? Date processing tends to differ among versions.

Comment: Also, can you use PowerShell? I bet that would make this easier.

Comment: @Pekka: Server is Win Server 2008 R2, and yes - Powershell would work too :-) I need to a) download a file from FTP, b) unzip it (that's where I need the filename for), and c) restore it to SQL Server

Comment: for powershell this link might help http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730960.aspx

Comment: @Pekka: Date processing in batch is non-existant. And the language didn't change much since NT 4.

Comment: @Johannes It is possible to process dates in batch files by parsing the output of the `date` command. It's kludgy, but possible. `date`s output differs from platform to platform.

Comment: @Pekka: Call me if you found a reliable solution across all possible locales. Even Rob van der Woude has some quite advanced methods for date parsing there and they still don't work on quite many locales. And `date`'s output only differs if the user in question has another language or a different locale. That's hardly an OS version difference.

Comment: @Johannes this is exactly why I recommend Powershell for date operations. You may be right about the locale differences - Win7, 2003 and 2008 Server indeed output the same date format. Point taken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something like a look up table:

```
set month_01=JAN
set month_02=FEB
set month_03=MAR
@rem ...

set number=02

for %%a in (month_%number%) do call set month_as_text=%%%%a%%

echo %month_as_text%
```

The value in `%number%` in the `for` loop is used to dereference the matching variable name.

Or even shorter:

```
set number=02

for /f "tokens=%number%" %%m in ("JAN FEB MAR APR ...") do set month_as_text=%m

echo %month_as_text%
```

---

**EDIT:**

Johannes suggests a shorthand for the 1st version:

```
set month_01=JAN
set month_02=FEB
set month_03=MAR
@rem ...

set number=02

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set month_as_text=!month_%number%!    

echo %month_as_text%
```

Comment: You can use delayed expansion to shorten array access to `!month_%number%!`.

Comment: @Johannes: I wasn't sure about that and couldn't find a quick reference. But you still have to define the array, thats why I'd prefer the second (shorter) solution. I'll add your sugestion anyway, thanks.

Comment: Yes, the second option is indeed nice :-) – sadly this only works for such a restricted set of items, since afaik the tokenizer only allows a maximum of 31 tokens.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer ! Helped me get one big step closer to my goal!

Answer (score 1):

You could always do the number-to-text translation by hand, like:

```
if %MM%==01 set MM=Jan
if %MM%==02 set MM=Feb
if %MM%==03 set MM=Mar
if %MM%==04 set MM=Apr
etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is incorrect for August and September. The reason is that the shell interprets a leading zero as octal, and 08 and 09 are not valid octal numbers. You can see this easily for yourself by running this command:

```
for /f "tokens=08" %a in ("A B C D E F G H I J") do echo %a
```

If you replace the `08` above with `09` it will also fail. It will work if you use `07` or `10`. A working implementation is as follows:

```
months=JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC
:: get the month as a 2-digit number
set number=%date:~4,2%
:: remove leading zero
for /f "tokens=* delims=0" %%a in ("%number%") do set number=%%a
:: index into array to get month name
for /f "tokens=%number%" %%m in ("%months%") do set month_as_text=%%m
:: print month name
echo %month_as_text%
```